# anti crawler - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I know to write Python crawler with beautiful soup module. Now I want to detect if someone crawls my website. How to do that. Can someone point me to pesudo code or sourcecode. Basically I am looking to write anti-crawler in python.

Comment: This simply can't be done.  You can do things to try to prevent the most simple approaches (blocking user-agents, watching for quick requests, using javascript injection, etc...) but you can't prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard, but can do things to filter crawlers.

**Auth**

Show pages only to authorized users.

**Strong Captcha**

If your captcha system strong enough, can anti a part of crawlers.

**User Agent**

Requests from crawler may not set user agent, so you can block those requests have no user agent(or not right user agent).

**Request Frequency**

Some crawler requests your website more faster than human, block their IP.

**JS load**

Using javascript to load your html, normal crawl only get the base html before javascript loading completed.

**Temporary URL**

Your can encode your url with timestamp(or something else) and public the url to user for visiting, making some crawlers cannot find entrance.

**Or Any other**

....

Answer (score 0):

What about assuming that not all crawlers are nasty? Most do respect the [robots directives](http://www.robotstxt.org/). Of course you can implement all sorts of heuristics to block robots but the first thing you do would be to have

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

in a robots.txt at the root of your site.

Then if you really want to make things hard for the ones who do not follow robots.txt then use Javascript for all the links : not 100% guaranteed to block robots but it will make their lives a lot more difficult.